# Making a very simple HTTP request from an HTTPS website

Tags: javascript, html, server, https, esp32

I'm trying to make a very elementary project, where pressing a button on a website connects to an ESP32 and turns on a light. I'm trying to allow websites from out of my local network to connect to this ESP32, so I set up port-forwarding on my router and it works whenever a GET request is sent to the router IP.

However, the website I have made is running on an HTTPS server, and it cannot make GET requests to the HTTP server my ESP32 is running. How can I overcome this?

The GET request is very simple, and I do not care about the response. The moment the ESP32 recieves the request, the light turns on.

The request doesn't go through as the ESP32 web server is on HTTP.

Comment: You will need a proxy server

Comment: Have you tried using node-http-proxy to build the proxy server?